# Execute function on class when load and resize (Jquery)

Tags: jquery, css, function, center, each

I have a problem with the following function. It's pupose is to center all divs with the class "center_vert" vertically to its parents. When the page is loaded, only the first div with the class "center_vert" is centert vertically. When I resize the page all elements are centered. Why are not all divs with the class "center_vert" centered on load?

```
$(document).load($(window).bind("resize", centerVertically));
$(document).ready(centerVertically ());

function centerVertically() {
    $('.center_vert').each(function(){
           var parentHeight = $(this).parent().height();   
           var selfHeight = $(this).height();   
           $(this).css('padding-top', function(i,x){return ((parentHeight-selfHeight)/2);});
    });
};
```

Comment: Could you provide us the html and the css?

Comment: CSS:

.center_vert {
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box
}

Comment: HTML is somthing like that:       

<div class="grid_100 tece window_60">
        <div class="center_vert"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid_100 tece window_60">
        <div class="center_vert"></div>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

Remove the empty space near the function name.
You should receive an error in your browser console related this error.

```
$(document).ready(centerVertically());
```

Comment: did it, still the same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution without JS:

```
<div class="grid_100 tece window_60">
    <div class="center_vert"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid_100 tece window_60">
    <div class="center_vert"></div>
</div>


.grid_100 {
    display:table;
    width: 100%;
}

.grid_100 > * {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this to the JS:

```
$(document).ready(setTimeout (centerVertically, 100));
```

I think, that the browser has to wait for the parent DIV's to be resized (done by JS depending on window height) and afterwards fire the "centerVertically" function. The funny thing about is, that my resizing code is before the "centerVertically" function in my JS file. I think its not a really clean solution but it works. Anybody an idea how I can get some better fix of this issue?

Here is the code, that resizes the divs:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).on('load resize', function(){
        $('.window_60').height($(window).height()*0.6);
    });
});
```